# Remove WooCommerce shipping method based on product attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205960/hide-shipping-methods-based-on-variation-product-attribute-in-woocommerce) referral.

I'm trying to remove shipping rates based on product attributes inside customer cart.

For example if cart contains product with `pa_size` attribute and values `30x50`, `50x70` in it, shipping method `flat_rate:3` will be removed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define the Product Attibute taxonomy (starts always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_size'; // Example for "Color"

    // HERE define shipping method rate ID to be removed from product attribute term(s) slug(s) (pairs) in this array

    // If site language is Hebrew
    if (get_locale() == 'he_IL') {
      $data_array = array(
          'flat_rate:3'      => array('30x50-he', '50x70-he', '50x70', '30x50')
      );
    }
    // Else site language
    else{
      $data_array = array(
          'flat_rate:3'      => array('50x70', '50x70-he')
      );
    }

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
            // The product attribute selected term slug
            $term_slug = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy];

            // Loop through our data array
            foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
                if( in_array($term_slug, $term_slugs) && isset($rates[$rate_id]) ) {
                    // We remove the shipping method corresponding to product attribute term as defined
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

It works, but I get conflict with WooCommerce files on wc-cart-functions.php file that in charge of shipping rate on cart file (which affect other functions in WordPress).

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php on line 477
```

How can I remove WooCommerce shipping method basing on attributes on user cart without conflict WooCommerce?

**Full error log:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php:477 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php(477): array_keys() #1 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php(413): wc_shipping_methods_have_changed() #2 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1454): wc_get_chosen_shipping_method_for_package() #3 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1423): WC_Cart->get_chosen_shipping_methods() #4 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/AbstractCartRoute.php(165): WC_Cart->calculate_shipping() #5 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/AbstractCartRoute.php(69): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\AbstractCartRoute->calculate_totals() #6 [internal function]: Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\AbstractCartRoute->get_response() #7 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1171): call_user_func() #8 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1018): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request() #9 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api.php(535): WP_REST_Server->dispatch() #10 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api.php(2884): rest_do_request() #11 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/Assets/AssetDataRegistry.php(317): rest_preload_api_request() #12 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/BlockTypes/AllProducts.php(40): Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Assets\AssetDataRegistry->hydrate_api_request() #13 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/BlockTypes/AllProducts.php(33): Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AllProducts->hydrate_from_api() #14 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/BlockTypes/AbstractBlock.php(100): Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AllProducts->enqueue_data() #15 [internal function]: Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->enqueue_editor_assets() #16 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): call_user_func_array() #17 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #18 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #19 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php(272): do_action() #20 /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/post-new.php(72): require('/var/www/vhosts...') #21 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/rockstar-z.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php on line 477
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing a full error log, and I haven't looked at what you're doing in any depth, but I can see that in wc-cart-functions.php at line 477, in the function `wc_shipping_methods_have_changed`, `array_keys` acts on `$package['rates']`, but that, in your function, `if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )`, you would not be returning anything.

So, you might try returning either array() or simply, probably safer, $rates. In other words:

```
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return $rates;

}
```

Anyway I'd at least try that. If the error persists, I'd look for anywhere else that `$package` or `$package['rates']` might be changed.

Comment: Thank you friend, I wasn't thinking its even related, didn't do any test outside admin panel.