# Hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on product attributes not used for variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

In my WooCommerce web site, each product has four product attributes (*Size*, *Color*, *Season* and *Brand*). The attributes *Size* and *Color* are used for variations, while *Season* and *Brand* are not  used for variations.

The aim is to hide free shipping for products of the "S24" *Season*. I am starting with the following code, but it only works with the attributes used for variations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define the Product Attibute taxonomy (starts always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_season'; // Example for "Color"

    // HERE define shipping method rate ID to be removed from product attribute term(s) slug(s) (pairs) in this array
    $data_array = array(
        'free_shipping:8'      => array('s24'),
        'flat_rate:17'   => array('f23'),
    );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
            // The product attribute selected term slug
            $term_slug = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy];

            // Loop through our data array
            foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
                if( in_array($term_slug, $term_slugs) && isset($rates[$rate_id]) ) {
                    // We remove the shipping method corresponding to product attribute term as defined
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

How to make it work for product attributes that are not used for variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product attributes that are not used in variations, you need first to get the parent variable product when the cart item is a product variation.

Then you can use 2 approaches:

1. Using `WC_Product` `get_attributes()` method *(the more secure way)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    // Product Attribute taxonomy (start always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_season'; // Example for "Season"

    // Array of Shipping method rate ID and term(s) slug(s) pairs
    $data_array = array(
        'free_shipping:8' => array('s24'),
        'flat_rate:17'    => array('f23'),
    );

    // Loop through items in the current shipping package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // Get the parent variable product if it's a product variation
        $product = $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($item['product_id']) : $item['data'];
            
        // Loop through our data array
        foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
            // loop through product attributes
            foreach($product->get_attributes() as $attribute ) {
                if( $attribute->get_taxonomy() === $taxonomy && isset($rates[$rate_id]) 
                && count( array_intersect($attribute->get_slugs(), $term_slugs) ) > 0 ) {
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

---

2. Using `WC_Product` `get_attribute( $attribute )` method, *(where `$attribute` can be the attribute taxonomy or the attribute label name)*:

As the method `get_attribute()` will return always a **string** of product **term(s) name(s)**, so we will use it **only when the targeted attribute has a unique term** set in the product.

Then in the code below, we will use term(s) name(s) instead of term(s) slug(s):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    // Product Attribute taxonomy (start always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_season'; // Example for "Season"

    // Array of Shipping method rate ID and term(s) NAME(s) pairs
    $data_array = array(
        'free_shipping:8' => array('S24'),
        'flat_rate:17'    => array('F23'),
    );

    // Loop through items in the current shipping package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // Get the parent variable product if it's a product variation
        $product = $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($item['product_id']) : $item['data'];
            
        // Loop through our data array
        foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_names ) {
            if( in_array($product->get_attribute($taxonomy), $term_names) && isset($rates[$rate_id]) ) {
                unset($rates[$rate_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Related: [Hide shipping methods based on Variation product attribute in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205960/hide-shipping-methods-based-on-variation-product-attribute-in-woocommerce/55206722#55206722)

Comment: Thank you very much @LoicTheAztec for your help. I used code no.1 you provided and achieved my goal. However, I would also like that when at least one product from S24 and at least one product from F23 are added to the shopping cart, only free shipping is available (ID:8). How do I change the code?

Comment: @LucaMoschetta Please ask a new question with your new requirements, adding in your new question your code attempt, even if it doesn't work… Then notify me here.